# Couldn't run SplashScreen and OnBoarding screen together

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

When I run my app, I can't see any Splash Screen.I did this from a video and I have set my AndroidManifest settings just like the one on the video. I located my SplashScreen on top of the MainActivity in Manifest file and set it to normal(just like the when I created my splash screen activity) but it still doesn't work.

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.labawsrh.aws.introscreen">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".finalActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".interests" />
        <activity android:name=".IntroActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

SplashScreen.java:

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, 3000);

    }
}
```

activity_splash_screen.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_gradient"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/whitegift"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Gift Finder"
        android:textSize="60dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/intoscript"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="130dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

IntroActivty.java (OnBoarding screen codes):

```
public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager screenPager;
    IntroViewPagerAdapter introViewPagerAdapter ;
    TabLayout tabIndicator;
    Button btnNext;
    int position = 0 ;
    Button btnGetStarted;
    Animation btnAnim ;
    TextView tvSkip;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // make the activity on full screen

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        // when this activity is about to be launch we need to check if its openened before or not

        if (restorePrefData()) {

            Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class );
            startActivity(mainActivity);
            finish();


        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

        // hide the action bar

        //getSupportActionBar().hide();

        // ini views
        btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        btnGetStarted = findViewById(R.id.btn_get_started);
        tabIndicator = findViewById(R.id.tab_indicator);
        btnAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.button_animation);
        tvSkip = findViewById(R.id.tv_skip);

        // fill list screen

        final List<ScreenItem> mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mList.add(new ScreenItem("Best Advice!","GiftFinder is an app that gives you the best gift advices.",R.drawable.advice));
        mList.add(new ScreenItem("How It Works?","Our AI code just needs couple info to find the best gift.",R.drawable.aicode));
        mList.add(new ScreenItem("Then..","Let the AI find the best gift for you!",R.drawable.ai));

        // setup viewpager
        screenPager =findViewById(R.id.screen_viewpager);
        introViewPagerAdapter = new IntroViewPagerAdapter(this,mList);
        screenPager.setAdapter(introViewPagerAdapter);

        // setup tablayout with viewpager

        tabIndicator.setupWithViewPager(screenPager);

        // next button click Listner

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                position = screenPager.getCurrentItem();
                if (position < mList.size()) {

                    position++;
                    screenPager.setCurrentItem(position);


                }

                if (position == mList.size()-1) { // when we rech to the last screen

                    // TODO : show the GETSTARTED Button and hide the indicator and the next button

                    loaddLastScreen();


                }



            }
        });

        // tablayout add change listener


        tabIndicator.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                if (tab.getPosition() == mList.size()-1) {

                    loaddLastScreen();

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });



        // Get Started button click listener

        btnGetStarted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //open main activity

                Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainActivity);
                // also we need to save a boolean value to storage so next time when the user run the app
                // we could know that he is already checked the intro screen activity
                // i'm going to use shared preferences to that process
                savePrefsData();
                finish();



            }
        });

        // skip button click listener

        tvSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                screenPager.setCurrentItem(mList.size());
            }
        });



    }

    private boolean restorePrefData() {


        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean isIntroActivityOpnendBefore = pref.getBoolean("isIntroOpnend",false);
        return  isIntroActivityOpnendBefore;



    }

    private void savePrefsData() {

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isIntroOpnend",true);
        editor.commit();


    }

    // show the GETSTARTED Button and hide the indicator and the next button
    private void loaddLastScreen() {

        btnNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnGetStarted.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvSkip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tabIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        // TODO : ADD an animation the getstarted button
        // setup animation
        btnGetStarted.setAnimation(btnAnim);



    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, try to remove these lines 
        if (restorePrefData()) {

            Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class );
            startActivity(mainActivity);
            finish();


        }
I think this could be the problem that why your view not visible

Comment: if I do this, i gotta remove the entire funcs bottom of the lines you said.

Comment: i'm running my app on my real phone, not virtual machine. i've just realized there are 2 same applications. why did happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SplashScreen` must be your launcher activity. You have `IntroActivity` as your launcher activity. Updated your  `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.labawsrh.aws.introscreen">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".finalActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".interests" />

          // Made SplashScreen Launcher Activity
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".IntroActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am new on android, and my solution could be not as normally you think is the right solution. First sorry for my bad english. In my opinion, the splash screen is only and elegant way for introduce you and your app. It must be fast and a short duration. I red a lot of solutions in internet but all pages and all snippets are at 90% the same (seems that many peoples have made cut / paste on the same first solution). So I decided to implement my own solution. Sorry for my raw code. I have implemented all in one Activity: and in your app you have to insert only this modifications:

-) Step one: **activity_main.xml** (main layout), include all in a FrameLayout:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id = "@+id/frameContainer">


        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The target FrameLayout (@id/frameContainer) is the splash screen container.

-) Step two: insert a bitmap in drawable directory, it should be the splash screen background, and in my example I have prepared also a rectangular space where insert my dynamic strings (for example "touch for start" and "Version n. 000.00.00"). My bitmap id is "@drawable/applogothumb", same in the string file, I have inserted a string "@string/toccasplash". On the bitmap I have also took the pixel coordinate of the rectangular space for the strings.

-) Step three: declaration and usage in the Main App:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Util.hideStatusBar(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Qui lancio la thumb, il controllo passato [ frameContainer ] deve essere
    //un FrameLayout in modo che la thumb stia sopra tutto il resto
    CMainSplashBox thumb = new CMainSplashBox(this,
            R.id.frameContainer,                //FrameLayout ID Step 1
            R.drawable.applogothumb,            //Bitmap ID Step 2
            R.string.toccasplash,               //Stringa ID
            CVersions.APP_VERSION,              //Version number (String)
            //pixel coordinate of the rectangular space for the strings
            new Rect(TWRITE_ORG_X,TWRITE_ORG_Y,TWRITE_END_X,TWRITE_END_Y),
            //Time duration in seconds
            10);                         
    mCsd = new CSerializeData(this);
    mCsd.loadConfiguration();
    ....
    ....
```

As you can see all is managed in the CMainSplashBox class. Nothing else i required. In the meanwhile the Splash screen is displayed the app can finisc to build the code and continue the execution.
All is in the class, the managing on the click for close it and the timer for the time count.
The class is here. Before you see the class, remember that this is my first experiment and the code inside is made for my own scope but I think there is materia for work on it or, may be, someone can suggest me how improve this Idea...

```
public class CMainSplashBox extends LinearLayoutCompat {
    private Timer statusCommandsTimer = null;
    private int mDurata = 5000; //seconds/1000
    private int mPeriodo = 1000;
    private FrameLayout padre;
    private CMainSplashBox figlio;
    private Context mCtx;
    private Bitmap mSplash;
    private int mIdSplash = -1;
    private String mText;
    private String mVer;
    private float DIM_X = 963;
    private float DIM_Y = 700;
    private float ORG_X = 95;
    private float ORG_Y = 475;
    private float END_X = 877;
    private float END_Y = 568;
    private int mFontMis = 70;
    private double mTotTxSpace = 50;
    private double mLfontD = 15;
    private double mBfontD = 28;

    /*
    @context = appContext
    @id = FrameLayout ID
    @idd = Bitmap ID
    @idText = String ID
    @ver = Version number string
    @th = Pixel coordinate
    @durata = wait in second
     */
    public CMainSplashBox(Context context,int id,int idd,int idText ,String ver, Rect 
                                    th,int durata){
        super(context);
        mCtx = context;
        mDurata = durata * 1000;
        mIdSplash = idd;
        ORG_X = th.left;
        ORG_Y = th.top;
        END_X = th.right;
        END_Y = th.bottom;
        mVer = "Version.: "+ver;
        mText = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getText(idText).toString();
        Point pt = Util.getOriginalBitmapDims(context.getResources(),idd);
        DIM_X = pt.x;
        DIM_Y = pt.y;
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams vgl = new 
                          FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT,MATCH_PARENT);
        vgl.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;
        figlio = this;
        padre = ((AppCompatActivity)context).findViewById(id);
        padre.addView(this);
        setBackgroundColor(0xCC000000);
        setLayoutParams(vgl);
        setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        setEnabled(true);
        statusCommandsTimer = startTimer(statusCommandsTimer,0, mPeriodo);
        setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //here I can close the Splash if the screen have been touched
                mDurata = 0;
            }
        });
    }

    //Draw the splash screen and make some calculations on the bitmaps
    //Util is my library with some common routines
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (mSplash == null){
            mSplash = Util.getBitmap(mCtx,mIdSplash,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight());
        }
        if (mSplash != null){
            int dmx = mSplash.getWidth();
            int dmy = mSplash.getHeight();
            float dx = (canvas.getWidth()-dmx)/2;
            float dy = (canvas.getHeight()-dmy)/2;
            canvas.drawBitmap(mSplash,dx,dy,null);
            int orgx = (int)(((ORG_X * dmx)/DIM_X)+dx);
            int orgy = (int)(((ORG_Y * dmy)/DIM_Y)+dy);
            int endx = (int)(((END_X * dmx)/DIM_X)+dx);
            int endy = (int)(((END_Y * dmy)/DIM_Y)+dy);
            Paint p = new Paint();
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            p.setTextSize(mFontMis);
            p.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mText.length(), bounds);
            p.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            int thumbw = (endx-orgx)-10;
            bounds.offset(0, -bounds.top);
            double spt = (bounds.height() * mTotTxSpace)/mBfontD;
            if ((endy-orgy) < (int)spt){
                mFontMis =(int)(((endy-orgy) * mFontMis) / spt);
                p.setTextSize(mFontMis);
                p.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mText.length(), bounds);
                bounds.offset(0, -bounds.top);
                spt = (bounds.height() * mTotTxSpace)/mBfontD;
                }
            if (thumbw < bounds.width()){
                mFontMis = (thumbw*mFontMis)/bounds.width();
                p.setTextSize(mFontMis);
                p.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mText.length(), bounds);
                bounds.offset(0, -bounds.top);
                }
            dmx = ((endx-orgx)-bounds.width())/2;
            dmy = (endy-orgy)-bounds.height();
            spt = bounds.height();
            p.setColor(0xff000000);                                        
            canvas.drawText(mText, orgx+dmx, endy-dmy, p);          
            int fm = (int)((mFontMis * mLfontD) / mBfontD);
            p.setTextSize(fm);
            p.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mVer.length(), bounds);
            bounds.offset(0, -bounds.top);
            dmx = ((endx-orgx)-bounds.width())/2;
            int spy = (int)(mTotTxSpace -(mLfontD+mBfontD));
            dmy = (int)((endy-orgy)-(bounds.height()+(((endy-orgy) * 
            spy)/mTotTxSpace)));
            canvas.drawText(mVer, orgx+dmx, (endy-dmy)+(float)spt, p);          
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if (mSplash != null) mSplash.recycle();
        mSplash = null;
        //Ridisegna
        invalidate();
    }

    // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // 
    // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // //
    // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // //    
    // Wait Timer

    private Timer startTimer(Timer tt, int delay, int period) {
        Timer itt = tt;
        if (itt == null) {
            itt = new Timer();
            itt.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TimeCounter();
                }
            }, delay, period);
        }
        return itt;
    }


    private void stopTimers(Timer tt) {
        if (tt != null) {
            tt.cancel();
            tt.purge();
        }
    }
    
    //Calculate the residual time
    private void TimeCounter(){
        mDurata -= mPeriodo;
        if (mDurata <= 0 && mCtx instanceof AppCompatActivity){
            stopTimers(statusCommandsTimer);
            ((AppCompatActivity)mCtx).runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
        }
    }

    //This function is necessary because I have to remove the splash screen and 
    //Remove the bitmap from the timer thread
    private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            setEnabled(false);
            setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            //for safety only  as you are doing onClick
            if(null!=padre && figlio != null) 
                padre.removeView(figlio);
            if (mSplash != null) mSplash.recycle();
        }
    };
    // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // 
    // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // //
    // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // 
}
```

Thats all. Any suggestions or improvements are welcome.

[image: this is the result]